# Deploy Dataflow job in CI/CD pipeline on Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-build

I have a Dataflow job that needs to be executed only once, when there is a push on the repository of other service. After that push is done I need to implement CI/CD that will update the new version of the service on the cloud. While executing those steps in the pipeline on Cloud Build I want to execute in one step the Dataflow job (that job is only once executed when there is new version). Is there any possible way to execute the Dataflow job in the pipeline step without Dataflow VM or is there any option that job to be done?

Comment: How long take your dataflow job? How many resources (CPU/RAM) do you need in your dataflow job?

Comment: yea you can run the beam pipeline directly in Python using the DirectRunner as a step in Cloud Build, but if the pipeline does anything complex, uses a lot of CPU, etc. then your build will time out and fail. In general, I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it is a short term job about 1 minute  and it doesn't use a lot of resources, I use it as activator to other services

Comment: So, did you consider to run your pipeline with a directRunner and not a dataflow runner?

Comment: Yes it worked with DirectRunner Here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906193/problem-with-installing-python-requirements-in-gcp-cloudbuild

@guillaumeblaquiere all credits to you xD