# Problem with Installing python requirements in GCP cloudbuild

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to run a  apache beam pipeline with DirectRunner in cloudbuild and by doing that I need to install the requirements for the python script, but I am facing some errors.
This is part of my cloudbuild.yaml

```
    steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', "gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=env --format='get(payload.data)' | tr '_-' '/+' | base64 -d > .env" ]
  id: GetSecretEnv
# - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
#   entrypoint: 'bash'
#   args: ['-c', 'gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600 && gcloud app deploy --quiet tweepy-to-pubsub/app.yaml']

- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  id: Access id_github
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: [ '-c', 'gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret=id_github> /root/.ssh/id_github' ]
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
# Set up git with key and domain
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  id: Set up git with key and domain
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_github
    cat <<EOF >/root/.ssh/config
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_github
    EOF
    ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
# Connect to the repository
  id: Connect and clone repository
  dir: workspace
  args:
  - clone
  - --recurse-submodules
  - git@github.com:x/repo.git
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh

- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args: [ '-c',
          'source /venv/bin/activate' ]
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3'  
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash' 
  dir: workspace
  args: ['pip', 'install','-r', '/dir1/dir2/requirements.txt']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3'
  entrypoint: 'python'
  dir: workspace
  args: [ 'dir1/dir2/script.py', 
         '--runner=DirectRunner' ]
timeout: "1600s"
```

Without the step where I install the requirements this works but I need the libs, because  I have python error for missing libs, and on the second step (5th actually in the original form of cloud build) the cloud build fails with this error

```
Step #5: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/x/dataflow-python3
Step #5: import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/360.
Step #5: import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/360.
Step #5: /usr/local/bin/pip: line 5: from: command not found
Step #5: /usr/local/bin/pip: pip: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Step #5: /usr/local/bin/pip: pip: line 7: `    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])'
```

How do I fix this? I also tried some examples on the internet and it doesn't work

Edit: First I deploy on app engine and then I download the repo in cloud build vm, install requirements and try to run it the python script

Comment: As per [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507096/python-error-import-unable-to-open-x-server) it could be an issue with the script.py file you are trying to run after installing the requirements. Are you sure it starts with the proper shebang character in a similar fashion to #!/usr/bin/env python ?

Comment: Can you share the full cloudbuild.yaml, or indicate in your code sample what is the step #5?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I edited the question now it is the full cloudbuild.yaml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue comes from your path definition

```
'source /venv/bin/activate'
```

and

```
'pip', 'install','-r', '/dir1/dir2/requirements.txt'
```

You use the full path definition and it doesn't work on Cloud Build. The current working directory is `/workspace/`. If you use relative path, add simply a dot `.` before the path, it should works better.

Or not... Indeed, you have the venv activation in a step, and the pip install in the following step. From one step to another, the runtime environment is offloaded and reloaded with the other container. Thus, your `source` command that set up environment variable, disappear in the `pip` step.

---

In addition, your cloud build environment is built for the build and destroy then. You don't need to use venv in this case and you can simplify the 3 last steps like this

```
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/dataflow-python3'
  entrypoint: '/bin/bash'
  args:
   - '-c'
   - |
       pip install -r ./dir1/dir2/requirements.txt
       python ./dir1/dir2/script.py --runner=DirectRunner
```